# Every time I run my remove duplicate copy/paste function format seems to off

Tags: excel, vba, format, copy-paste

I have a code which takes data from one sheet, copies it, removes duplicates then pastes into another sheet. The function itself works, but the format messes up as I will show you.

Here is the code:

```
Sub CopyAndPaste()

Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet

Set s1 = Sheets("Job Plan in Order")
Set s2 = Sheets("Job Plan Final")

s2.Range("F8").Resize(s1.Cells(s1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row - 1).Value = s1.Range("B9:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value

s2.Range("F8:F400").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo


End Sub
```

This is what happens on the excel sheet - the messed up format is the column where green is present it for some reason deletes the green:

[image]

Comment: Where exactly is the green removed from? The `RemoveDuplicates` method will fill the space left by removed duplicate cells with unformatted blank cells (below the unique cells remaining) - is that consistent with what  you see?

Comment: its removed from after JP021, there is other data there but its just blank right now. Im not sure why the formatting gets ruined.

Answer (score 2):

### Remove Duplicates in a Column Range (Dictionary)

- `RemoveDuplicates` will shift up the cells, hence the white cells. You can figure this out by testing with various values.

You could replace the line ...

```
s2.Range("F8:F400").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
```

... with the line...

```
RemoveColumnDupes s2.Range("F8:F400")
```

... which utilizes the following procedure...

```
Sub RemoveColumnDupes(ByVal ColumnRange As Range)
    
    If ColumnRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    With ColumnRange.Columns(1)
        
        Dim rCount As Long: rCount = .Rows.Count
        
        Dim Data As Variant
        If rCount = 1 Then
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            Data = .Value
        End If
        
        Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        
        Dim Key As Variant
        Dim s As Long, d As Long
        
        For s = 1 To rCount
            Key = Data(s, 1)
            If Not IsError(Key) Then
                If Len(Key) > 0 Then
                    If Not dict.Exists(Key) Then
                        d = d + 1
                        Data(d, 1) = Key
                        dict(Key) = Empty
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next s
        
        If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        
        .Resize(d).Value = Data
        .Resize(rCount - d).Offset(d).ClearContents
        
    End With
            
End Sub
```

... which kind of mimics `RemoveDuplicates` but without the shifting.

Comment: which parts of your code need to be changed to match my needs?

Comment: In your `Sub` you only have to replace the one line mentioned at the beginning. Then copy the complete `Sub RemoveColumnDupes` to your module (e.g. to the bottom). Then your `Sub` will call my `Sub` and do the job i.e. you run your `Sub`, mine cannot run by itself because of the `ColumnRange` argument.